# How to open a window in floating when workspace has no windows?

Tags: i3

I would like to have i3 open up a window in float mode when only one window is open per workspace. Once another window is opened it goes back to horizontal tiled mode.

Is making an application open in float mode and then doing `$mod+Shift+Space` the only way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `floating enable` for the `window_role` or `class` in the i3 config file.

Eg. To always open Firefox in floating mode, add the following to your i3 config file

```
for_window [window_role=browser] floating enable
```

or

```
for_window [class="Firefox"] floating enable
```